# Is it possible for Evolution to translate emails?

Tags: email, evolution, translation

I'm receiving emails in German through Gnome/Evolution that I'm interested in reading, but I need to translate them.

I have searched for Plugins but I haven't found them ([EvolutionPlugins](https://wiki.debian.org/EvolutionPlugins)).

Does anyone else have this need or found a way to solve it?

I use *Gnome/Evolution 3.44.4* on *Kubuntu 22.04*.

Answer (score 2):

I use Thunderbird with the translation add-on as Evolution does not have any (the last time I searched)